# Placing text view pixel-perfectly on image

Tags: android

I have image view with some lines and curves on it. I need to place the text labels into specific locations on this image. How it can be done? 
In details:
Look at the image http://s9.postimg.org/63bq7ax4f/e7c5d09764c43a10537ea1b92a0c0c8b.png
I need "92 PAC" and "95 DRI" to be on that line as well as 2 lines below. Now it shifts upside or downside on different screen sizes.
P.S. If it can simplify the problem, the image can be only in one fixed size in one dpi bucket (despite it's incorrect from the android style).

Thank's

Comment: For scaling reasons it’s important that you use an ImageView to draw the image, and not a background of another layout. I’m not sure it would work, but I would try with a percentage-based layout, like the [PercentFrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html).

Comment: Yes, I used ImageView src instead of background for layout. I tried to play with percentage earlier and now, but was not lucky. I suppose it is possible solution if to count the image view size and passit into corresponding layout for card content, but making custom view sounds more correct. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a custom view.  In your onDraw function, draw that image as a bitmap, then draw the text exactly where you want.

Comment: Completed the custom view with text labels and images. It solves the problem, thank you